# find and zip multiple file extensions while keeping the folder structure

Tags: bash, find, zip

Ubuntu 16.04

I would like to backup all .txt, .cfg, and .ini files, while keeping their folder structure to a zip file in the backups folder.

I know there is an easier way to do this entire operation but this is what I have.

```
#!/bin/bash

wdir="/home/files"
backup_dir="/home/files/backup"
allcfg=$(find suan -name '*.cfg')
alltxt=$(find suan -name '*.txt')
allini=$(find suan -name '*.ini')
timeStamp="$(date +%Y--%b-%d--%k:%M--%P)"
backupfilename="${backup_dir}/Backup-${timeStamp}.zip"

#-- set some arrays ...
backupfiles=( "$allcfg" "$alltxt" "$allini" )

cd "$wdir"
zip -r "$backupfilename" "$backupfiles"
```

So I can see a nice output of the files it files but when it gets to the zipping part it errors out.

`zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -r /home/files/backup/Backup-2018--Jul-04--21:37--pm.zip . -i suan/cfg/360controller.cfg`

But that doesn't work either.

Comment: When you quoted the variables, the filenames individuality is lost. Try the array option or do everything within `find`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how the `-r` recursive option on `7z` works, it's a recursive pattern search.

```
7z a -r "$backupfilename" \*.ini \*.cfg \*.txt
```

`7z` creates zip files just fine.

You could also do the multi-arg option on `find` if you somehow don't have 7zip,

```
find suan \( -name \*.cfg -o -name \*.txt -o -name \*.ini \) \
    -exec zip -r "$backupfilename" {} +
```

Comment: @thill Excellent!

Answer (score 1):

Using `find` and `zip`:

```
find "$wdir" -type f '(' -name '*.cfg' -o -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.ini' ')' \
    -exec zip -r "$backupfilename" {} +
```

You may alternatively want to let your script `cd` into `"$wdir"` first and then use `.` in the `find` command, depending on what path you'd like to have saved in the archive.

This would find all relevant files and archive them in your backup file.

Alternatively with `bash`, if there's not thousands of files:

```
set -s globstar nullglob dotglob
cd "$wdir" && zip -r "$backupfilename" **/*.ini **/*.cfg **/*.txt
```

The shell options that are set here enables the `**` glob (which globs pathnames), makes unexpanded globs expand to the empty string and makes globs match hidden files.